# sqlite query that outputs into specific order

Tags: sqlite

Not sure if this possible or not but I have a data set with random transaction information.
The data looks like

```
Date Pass_fail
2020-04-01 Pass
2020-04-01 Fail
2020-04-02 Pass
2020-04-03 Pass
2020-04-03 Fail
2020-04-04 Fail
2020-04-04 Pass
```

I am specifically looking to have the output of a query display the transactions with a pass and then fail. so like this

```
Date Pass_fail
2020-04-01 Pass
2020-04-01 Fail
2020-04-03 Pass
2020-04-03 Fail
```

All information is stored in a single table (transactions), not sure if this is possible or where to start?

thanks!!!!

Comment: Where are `2020-04-02` and `2020-04-04` in your expected results?

Comment: @forpas yes sorry! just left it out of the second example.

Comment: Also what if there is only 'Pass' or 'Fail' for certain dates?

Comment: I believe the idea he's looking for is that when there is a change from say pass to fail to display those. So if it passes for an infinite number of transations for example then there would be no output but rather when it jumps to a fail display the passing row and then the failing one

Comment: @Pittsie yes! thats it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the boolean expression `Pass_fail = 'Fail'` which evaluates `1` or `0` in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT Date, Pass_fail 
FROM transactions
ORDER BY Date, Pass_fail = 'Fail'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d89e85f1a8dea1a3a5a33704adc3f8c1).